# the view from viewForFooterInSection animated unexpected when I call insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToBeInserted withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == someSection) {
        UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor];
        return footerView;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == someSection) {
        return 10;
    } 
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Nothing really special.
Just provide a footer view and trigger the insert rows method somehow, the footer view will be animated like dropping down every time, you can watch this easier by turning slow animations on in the simulator.

I don't know how to make the animation gone, it's really unwanted.

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740518/uitableview-footer-stop-from-floating-over-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a similar issue here - [UITableView section footer view position after endUpdates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240549/uitableview-section-footer-view-position-after-endupdates)

**The solution is to change table view style to Grouped.**