# animation issue with UITableView footer View when performing "beginUpdates" "endUpdates"

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, footer

When I'm changing a cell height with animation (using beginUpdates(), endUpdates()) I'm having a very weird animation for my section footer : it's moving at the bottom of the tableview.

here is the simplest code i could write

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "footer"
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeight
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    cellHeight += 20;
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

How could I avoid this animation issue ?

Comment: I am wondering how this code would even work. What do you mean by `cellHeight += 20`?

Comment: Does it stay at the bottom or is it just a temporary state?

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740518/uitableview-footer-stop-from-floating-over-content

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem (the footer moves to the bottom of the tableview and stays there).
It looks like it's an iOS8 bug (it doesn't happen on iOS7).

In my case, a workaround is to return the footer as the next section header...