# Footer overlays on top of tableview cell contents while scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tablefooterview

I have added `footerview` programmatically for each section as follows. I could able to see the `footerview`.

However, when I scroll up or down at the bottom or at the top of the tableview, `footerview` overlays on top of `tableviewcells`.

How could I able to disable it?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(adminOrderElements[section].expanded && [adminOrderElements[section].notes length]>0)
    {
        return 60;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

    return 60;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
    footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:footer.frame];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl.text = @"Your Text";
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [footer addSubview:lbl];

    return footer;
}
```

**Before Scroll**

[image]

**After Scroll**

[image]

Comment: What height is your `heightForFooterInSection` returning? 60 or 0?

Comment: If there is a `footerview`, it is `60`. if not, then it is `0` based on the     `if(adminOrderElements[section].expanded && [adminOrderElements[section].notes length]>0)`

Comment: I would suggest adding a breakpoint on else part where you are returning 0 and check whether it goes there and I think you dont need second return 60   statement

Comment: @Paulw11 and @user1000 If you check the first image, `Order 4` does not have any content to show on the `footerview`, that is why there is no footer view, in other words the height is `0`. But `Order 3` has some content, therefore, the height of footer view is `60` and you could able to see label (`Your Text`) there.

Comment: I think your code is fine , please give the color say blue to section footer , and scroll , you will see its working fine and its not overlapping its supposed to be there, please check

Comment: What do you think about this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740518/uitableview-footer-stop-from-floating-over-content

Comment: You are asking to make     `footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
 to     `footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` and test?

Comment: Do you require your footer to be the end of the table or end of the section?And yes please change the color to blue

Comment: I want to add `footerview` for `each section` not for entire `tableview`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150672/discussion-between-user1000-and-hotspring).

Comment: By design table cells will go "under" the footer; You need to use an opaque colour for your footer

Comment: could you please illustrate with code?

Comment: As per your code I think you are returning a new UIView object as footerview for each section even for those section for which you dont want to display footerview and thats the problem. So, I think you should return empty view when footer is not there, so you can also conditions to viewForFooterInSection for checking if you want to show footerview or not and then return foorterview object or nil.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you only have to change the `UITableViewStyle` to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewstyle/1614942-grouped), for table views using grouped style *the section headers and footers do not float*.